# Detect Vuetify radio re-select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a wizard where choosing a radio button also triggers a navigation. It's also possible to go back to change previous choices. The issue I'm then running into is that there doesn't seem to be a good way to detect a re-select of a radio button in Vuetify.

- `@change` is only triggered on change
- There are no `@click` or `@input` events
- Listening to the `@mouseup` will cancel the `@change`

Ideally I'm am to do something like:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <div v-if="step === 0">
      <h1>Wizard: step 1</h1>
      <v-radio-group 
        v-model="fruit" 
        label="Pick your fruit"
        @input="step++"
      >
        <v-radio
          value="apple"
          label="Apple"
        />
        <v-radio
          value="orange"
          label="Orange"
        />
      </v-radio-group>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="step === 1">
      <h1>Wizard: step 2</h1>
      <p>Prev choice: {{fruit }}</p>
      <v-btn @click="step--">Go back</v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    step: 0,
    fruit: "apple"
  })
}
</script>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/peteruithoven/pen/qBbGMPL

A workaround I figured out is adding a click to a wrapping div and then ignoring clicks on the div itself.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <div v-if="step === 0">
      <h1>Wizard: step 1</h1>
      <v-radio-group 
        v-model="fruit" 
        label="Pick your fruit"
      >
        <div @click="onClick" ref="clickDetector">
          <v-radio
            value="apple"
            label="Apple"
          />
          <v-radio
            value="orange"
            label="Orange"
          />
        </div>
      </v-radio-group>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="step === 1">
      <h1>Wizard: step 2</h1>
      <p>Prev choice: {{fruit }}</p>
      <v-btn @click="step--">Go back</v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    step: 0,
    fruit: "apple"
  }),
  methods: {
    onClick(event) {
      if(event.target !== this.$refs.clickDetector) {
        this.step++;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Codepen with workaround: https://codepen.io/peteruithoven/pen/KKVLGdR

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: one workaround is set default value with `this.fruit=''`, then if the users go back, reset it to `''`. It will force the users have to choose one radio button instead of you choose one for them initially.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to target the native click event, like:

```
<v-radio
    value="apple"
    label="Apple"
    @click.native="onSelection('apple')"
/>
```

I would also consider just using a button if you can, since that's what most users might expect.

Comment: Good point on the button. I'm afraid that with this approach I still need a (event.target !== this.$refs.clickDetector) kind of check to ignore clicks on the background.

Comment: Correcting myself, I was assuming you where suggesting a click.native on the radio group, but you're suggesting adding it on the individual radio buttons which prevents the issue I mentioned before and does work well.

Comment: Great, yes it seems to fire on click on both the button and label.